# Can a native English speaker get what 'monochrome kiss' suggests without knowing the plot or lyrics?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Please take a moment to think about what impression the phrase, 'monochrome kiss', gives you before reading on.

---

***Monochrome Kiss*** is the name of the opening theme of the anime *[Black Butler](https://myanimelist.net/anime/4898/Kuroshitsuji#:%7E:text=In%20Ciel%27s%20past,can%20tear%20apart.)* whose premise is as follows.

> In Ciel's past lies a secret tragedy that enveloped him in perennial darkness—during one of his bleakest moments, he formed a contract with Sebastian, a demon, bargaining his soul in exchange for vengeance upon those who wronged him. Today, not only is Sebastian one hell of a butler, but he is also the perfect servant to carry out his master's orders—all the while anticipating the delicious meal he will eventually make of Ciel's soul. As the two work to unravel the mystery behind Ciel's chain of misfortunes, **a bond forms between them that neither heaven nor hell can tear apart**.

So, you can see that the anime is about the homosexual romance between two males. In the meanwhile, 'monochrome' means '*[made with a single color or hue](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monochrome#:%7E:text=made%20with%20a%20single%20color%20or%20hue)*'. Putting things together, we can come to the conclusion that the name *monochrome kiss* should mean *homosexual kiss*, which can be further verified by its lyrics as quoted at the end of this question.

Can a native English speaker get what 'monochrome kiss' suggests without knowing the plot? I wonder if this use of 'monochrome' is common or at least not unusual. Say, if I write a novel about homosexual with a title including 'monochrome', will a native speaker link 'monochrome' to 'homo-' without finding it weird?

---

[The lyrics](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/amalee/monochromekissblackbutler.html)

> In black and white, no whisper of colour
>
> In monochrome, we met each other
>
> I'll put my faith in my pain
>
> In you to keep safe
>
> The Autumn wind is so unforgiving
>
> Much like the scars that trace my body
>
> Your icy touch I trust
>
> I feel it beckoning me
>
> I was melting away and breaking
>
> But then you tenderly saved me from myself
>
> Fate is the game we're playing
>
> And it starts with a monochrome kiss
>
> Nevertheless, I'm searching on
>
> Looking for a single drop of love
>
> I look into your eyes; eyes that have never once cried
>
> They tell a tale beyond time
>
> And if I can, I'll seek the end
>
> Shrouded in my pain just as I am
>
> Hiding within the night, together we'll find it
>
> Under the light of the moon
>
> How many nights have I loved in your wake?
>
> I've come to know, to see your heartache
>
> I need you here with me
>
> Without you, I forget to breathe
>
> With your gaze I am captivated
>
> But I am finding it holds no warmth at all
>
> Now all the rules are changing
>
> But I despise how you lie with a kiss
>
> I'm begging please, don't leave me alone
>
> Colour in my heart, right to my soul
>
> Lulling me to sleep, lies I have always believed
>
> So tell a tale in my dreams
>
> I'm so confused, I've lost my mind
>
> Whisper soft as I'm closing my eyes
>
> Finding all that was lost, your smile the cost was
>
> Under the light of the moon
>
> I was melting away and breaking
>
> But then you tenderly saved me from myself
>
> Fate is the game we're playing
>
> And it all starts with a monochrome kiss
>
> Nevertheless, I'm searching on
>
> Looking for a single drop of love
>
> I look into your eyes; eyes that have never once cried
>
> They tell a tale beyond time
>
> And if I can, I'll seek the end
>
> Shrouding in my pain just as I am
>
> Your wish in the dark, shining in bay like the dawn
>
> A barely new tomorrow
>
> So pay it again
>
> So passionate; A braveless kiss on my lips
>
> Hiding within the night together we'll find it
>
> My final night under the moon

Comment: Without reading all that lot [which I didn't], no. First assumption could be something dull, uninteresting; something with all the life & vibrancy removed. Like a grey day, but worse.

Comment: Is there some way in which you're not just asking for an opinion? Can you explain how this question could be answered with verifiable fact?

Comment: @gotube You can list English songs by a native speaker which use it that way.

Comment: Used what way? Did you mean to ask @gonefishin'again. instead of me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Monochrome has literally sense of "one colour" or "only shades of grey", and a metaphorical sense of "dull and boring", "lacking emotional variety".  Collins gives "devoid of any distinctive or stimulating characteristics".

It doesn't have a common metaphorical sense of "homosexual".

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Gasai [monokuma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monokuma) from danganronpa? monokuma is a pun on monochrome (and a pun on kuma, japanese for bear). monochrome in this case is like plastic or fake.

> Fate is the game we're playing
>
> And it starts with a monochrome kiss
>
> Nevertheless, I'm searching on
>
> Looking for a single drop of love

meaning the kiss did not have even a single drop of love!

I haven't seen black butler though. are the lyrics meant to be from ciel to sebastian or something? hahaha black butler is a yaoi? I can't believe none of my so-called anime friends told me about this!!! LOL. They're sure gonna get an earful from me.